# What was edited here?

Tags: discussion, edits, revision-history, specific-edit

I just came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615239/label-called-outside-the-loop-isnt-accessible-from-outside-the-loop) with some edits, [the third revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39615239/3) of the question states "added 24 characters in body" but I can't spot any differences.

What was edited here?

Comment: An explicit language block - look at the side by side markdown on http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39615239/revisions

Comment: @JonClements I see, I thought this was a bug for a moment but good to know it was just me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the page you linked, showing only a single revision, you can *never* see what has been edited. On the page with [all revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39615239/revisions), there's a button to switch to the markdown diff, as noted by [Jon Clements ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334966/what-was-edited-here#comment397720_334966):

[image]

The edit is quite pointless, as the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag already makes sure the code is formatted as C.

Comment: Not to mention the correct syntax is: `<!-- language: lang-c -->` so if someone wants to edit it out...